heute Nacht = tonight or last night?
Is "heute Nacht" sometimes used in German for the night of the previous day? I have just heard/read the following sentence in the "Schlafende Hunde" TV series:

Man fand ihn heute Nacht auf einem Spielplatz in Kreuzkölln.

This sentence is said in the morning, so it's impossible that the speaker is talking about today's night, which starts after the sunset. My guess is the translation to English is "He was found in a playground last night in Kreuzkölln".

You can sort of do the same thing in English, up to a point. If the body was discovered at 11 PM and you’re a detective on a night shift talking about it six hours later, you could still say, “He was found in a playground earlier tonight”, even though it’s technically now the following morning. You wouldn’t get away with it at 7 PM the following evening in English, though.

Maybe, but I think "He was found in a playground earlier this evening" would be more common. Anyway, nobody would say that in the morning, as it's the case in the TV series.

You wouldn’t say ‘earlier this evening’ if he was found at 2 AM, though. And no, if ‘in the morning’ means ‘after sleeping and getting up in the morning’, then you wouldn’t – it only works if the night in question is still ongoing (i.e., roughly, if you haven’t gone to bed yet).

The term "heute Nacht" (literally: today [at] night) can mean both: the night before day broke or the coming night. Which one is meant depends on context:

Heute Nacht hatte ich einen schlechten Traum.
Heute Nacht werde ich ruhig schlafen.

The first sentence refers to the night that was, the second to the night which comes. Here (this is one possibility, but not the only one) the context is established by the tenses used: Präteritum (about: past tense) in the first, Futur (future tense) in the second.
Since your example sentence is in Präteritum ("man fand ihn) said context points to last night, not the coming one.

Schwierig wird das mit Satz 1 um 23:50 Uhr und Satz 2 um 0:05 Uhr. :)

Nacht is the time between Abend (evening) and Morgen (morning).
If someone says heute Nacht in the morning and is talking about the past (fand) then it's about the night before this morning but it doesn't have to be after midnight even though it would be logical in combination with heute.
So: if someone says heute Nacht it could be last night or the coming night. If the verb is in a present or future tense, we're talking about the following night, if in past about last night.

Heute Nacht habe ich super gut geschlafen.
Heute Nacht machen wir eine Nachtwanderung.
Heute Nacht werde ich kein Auge zubekommen.


Siehe meinen Kommentar bei Bakunin.

Yes. The Oxford-Duden and Langenscheidt dictionaries as well as reverso.com confirm it can mean either tonight or last night.

Both?
The thing is if you count night as roughly between evening and morning and let your 24-h day start at midnight (or "mid of the night") then there are logically 2 nights per day. That is one half-night before morning and one half-night after evening.
So heute Nacht could refer to both the past night or the upcoming night. Which one it actually refers to is probably not that hard to figure out given the present time of the day. So if it is somewhere between sunrise and sun set and you're talking in past tense about "heute Nacht", then it's likely you're talking about last night. While if you talk about what you're going to do "heute Nacht" then it's probably the upcoming night.
Also don't overthink the usage of hours that your clock displays and concepts like night and day. Once you've established whether "heute Nacht" refers to the last or the upcoming night, well "Nacht" refers to the whole period of external darkness. Sometimes it even goes beyond the period of darkness and stretches to the time of the day that you decided your sleep ought to end even if that's not what other people would call "night". It should start during the night hours though.

Another caveat: German uses present tense also with a future meaning. Which means your claim “Like if you say it during the day so that the other night hasn't even started, then it obviously refers to past events.” Is misleading at best and incorrect at worst. Without at least a verb in any past tense, it will have future meaning -  the upcoming night. And I can’t follow the logic of your last paragraph, can you please clarify?

If you want to stick to logic, the night before morning is between midnight and sunrise. 11:30 PM of yesterday is yesterday's night, not today's. However, German native speakers confirmed "heute Nacht" is used even for events before midnight. I think it's more productive to tell people to memorize the usage instead of trying to find logic where there isn't.
